# Capitalising "subdistrict", "district", "province" or not

Tags: british-english, capitalization, government

I write about crimes for a small local newspaper and often have to mention the location where the crime had happened.

The official (translated) hierarchy used in the country I live in is province -> district -> subdistrict.

My problem is that I don't know whether these words are supposed to be capitalised or not. I write in British English.

Here are some examples I've made up where I refrain from capitalising.

1. "(...) a gated community in Donsai subdistrict (...)"
2. "(...) who lives in the district of Wichasira (...)"
3. "(...) he was arrested in Chatong province (...)"
4. "(...) a road connecting the two subdistricts Talang and Saitai (...)"

Is there any rule for this?

Comment: The style used by the newspaper for which you write would be the best guide.

Comment: You usually capitalize the words in a Proper Name...........so if province is part of the name, it would be capitalized.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There might be different, specific rules in the culture of the country you live in and generally, if it's part of an official address then it not only deserves but clearly needs capitalization.

Xanne's style-guide suggestion is wholly sound.

When you say 'Here are some examples I've made up where I refrain from capitalising' how is that none of your examples in fact refrains from capitalizing which all of them clearly embrace?

Comment: Word mix-up. Sorry for that.

Comment: Uh… thanks and in that case, could you go back and correct it, please?